# COM object has a handle to a file that needs to be deleted before GC

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, com, garbage-collection

I have a .NET application that is using a bunch of COM objects (ESRI ArcGIS) to convert some data in a file from one format and export it to a file in another format.

I've tried looking for an ArcGIS solution to this problem but was unsuccessful after a day or so of research, so I haven't included that tag on this question, as it's ultimately unimportant which COM objects they are.

Okay, so the problem is when there is an exception during the export process. I catch the exception, present a message to the user, and delete export file.

The problem is that `File.Delete` call throws an exception because the COM object associated with the data export still has a handle to the file, the COM object itself has no "close" method, and GC has not reclaimed that memory yet.

Here is the code:

```
            try {
                ...
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(outputFolder) && File.Exists(pgdbPath))
                {
                    // Release all references to com object holding a handle to the .mdb file.
                    int refs;
                    var targetWorkspaceName = GetWorkspaceName(pgdbPath, "esriDataSourcesGDB.AccessWorkspaceFactory");

                    // COM object w/ handle to file at 'pgdbPath'
                    var targetWorkspace = GetWorkspace(targetWorkspaceName);
                    do
                    {
                        refs = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(targetWorkspace);
                    } while (refs > 0);

                    // Need to use GC to clean up the unmanaged memory pointed to by released references.
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                    // would throw file access exception without GC.
                    File.Delete(pgdbPath);             
                }

                throw;
            }
```

I'm relatively new to working with COM objects in .NET, but is there no other way to release a reference and clean up the memory associated with an object other than forcing garbage collection? I hate to do it. Thanks.

Comment: The com object likely releases the file when all references to it are released, the RCW (Runtime callable wrapper) will release it's reference when it's collected. You can get the RCW to release it's reference early with [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx), but this will leave the RCW unusable, so you need to be sure it isn't being used elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Note: this will only release the reference held directly by the RCW. If com object 'A' has it's own reference to com object 'B' and you have an RCW for each, then you will need to release both before 'B' is finally cleaned up.

Comment: Please do cross-check your COM object documentation. It is possible that there is a method in the COM object to close the file.